# How can I send CSV rows to Prometheus Pushgateway?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I have a simple csv file with date columns and numbers like this:

date       | count

2020-09-01 | 3

2020-09-02 | 4

2020-09-03 | 2

...

There is a python script that reads the csv row by row.

What I would like to do, using pushgateway, pushgateway will run the python script as a batch job and it will take the all csv time series data. At the end I will monitor it usign the grafana.